# Obtaining a Spring LocalResolver via RequestContext vs. via Injection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, locale

It technical is possible to obtain a [`LocaleResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html) instance in two different ways:

- via [`RequestContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContext.html):  [`RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html#getLocaleResolver%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) or
- via Injection: `@Autowired LocaleResolver localeResolver`

but which is the better way?

---

Background/Context:

I have implemented a customized variation Locale Change Interceptor. That is a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) that works a bit like the normal [`LocaleChangeInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html), and it used the injection way to obtain the `LocaleResolver`. It worked.

But today I have had a closer look on the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`. I noticed that they don't inject the `LocaleResolver` but obtain them from the Request Context (`RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)`)*.

Now I am a bit worried whether or not I overlooked **a pitfall or something similar when obtaining the `LocaleResolver` via injection in a `HandlerInterceptor` ?** - Any ideas?

---

- @See: [`LocaleResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html)
- @See: [`LocaleChangeInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html)
- @See: [`RequestContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContext.html)

**The [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) holds an instance of `LocaleResolver` (obtained via Injection or self created) and put them in every request context for every request.*

Comment: What type of `LocaleResolver` bean have you declared?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I use the same customized change interceptor in two projects, one with SessionLocaleResolver and the other with CookieLocaleResolver. Do you believe that the answer dependents on the LocaleResolver? (when yes, please tell me why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any pitfalls.

The `RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(HttpServletRequest)` is implemented as

```
public static LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (LocaleResolver) request.getAttribute(DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

In other words, it is getting it from the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. The use of `DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE` gives us a hint that the `DispatcherServlet` might be setting it. Its `initLocaleResolver()` method is implemented as

```
private void initLocaleResolver(ApplicationContext context) {
    try {
        this.localeResolver = context.getBean(LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME, LocaleResolver.class);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Using LocaleResolver [" + this.localeResolver + "]");
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        // We need to use the default.
        this.localeResolver = getDefaultStrategy(context, LocaleResolver.class);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name '" + LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME +
                    "': using default [" + this.localeResolver + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

So it's getting its `LocaleResolver` from the context or generates it from some default configuration, ie. `DispatcherServlet.properties` resource.

In conclusion, if you are declaring a `LocaleResolver` bean, both injecting it with `@Autowired` and getting it from `RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)` will get the same instance. See the `DispatcherServlet#doService(..)` method's

```
[...]
request.setAttribute(LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE, this.localeResolver);
[...]
```

---

`LocaleChangeInterceptor` uses the `static` utility because it isn't a bean in the Spring sense. It's a Spring MVC component that is not necessarily part of the `WebApplicationContext` and therefore doesn't belong in its life cycle, ie. it can't have anything injected.

Comment: So the only remaining pitfall would be, if the Dispatcher servlet, creates the LocalResolver itself (by its DefaultStrategy)?

Comment: @Ralph Well, if it doesn't find a `LocaleResolver` in the application context, that also means there won't be a candidate for injection, so your application wouldn't start up anyway.